# How to get invoice of current date only using stripe in python?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe API to get the invoice JSON and pdf link to download the invoice.
Now, whenever I request the invoice API returns me all the invoices JSONs.
My question is how I can get only today's transaction invoices, using any argument, or how this could be possible through python logic if there is no argument.

My code:

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = 'my_secret_key'   
invoices = stripe.Invoice.list(limit=100)
print(f'Total Invoices: {len(invoices)}')
print(invoices)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

docs suggest you can add a created parameter to  Invoice.list and pass a dictionary with greater than / less than timestamps.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/list?lang=python#list_invoices-created

Comment: and what should be the value of created parameter?
invoices = stripe.Invoice.list(limit=100,created=?)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this API to list all `Invoices`, or list all invoices for a specific `Customer`, that is created at a certain time see https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/list#list_invoices-created-gte. Note the `created` parameters are in **seconds**.

So if you want to list *all* `Invoices` created today (e,g, Sat, 13 Mar 2021 00:00:00 GMT), then you can write something like (of course you'll have to convert to the Python-equivalent...)

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> createdParams = new HashMap<>();
createdParams.put("gte", "1615593600");
params.put("created", createdParams);

InvoiceCollection invoices = Invoice.list(params);
```

Comment: What does this number means (1615593600)?

Comment: That's unix timestamp in seconds. It corresponds to the date I stated in my answer. Hope this helps!